# Double integral by numerical method in python- can't spot the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am writing this numerical method formula of trapezium rule for double integrals. [image]

Note that hx = (b-a)/nx, hy = (d-c)/ny to get the interval widths and xj = a+hx*j and yi = c+hy*i

When I test this on function t, I get 1.12 when the answer should be 0.66? Can anyone see what I am doing wrong- is it indentation?

```
from numpy import * 
from matplotlib.pylab import * 

def double_integral(f,a,b,c,d,nx,ny):
hx = (b-a)/nx
hy = (d-c)/ny 
integral = (hx*hy*0.25)*(f(a,c)+f(a,d)+f(b,c)+f(b,d))
    for i in range (1,ny-1):
      for j in range(1,nx-1):
        o = (hx*hy*0.5) 
        integral = integral + o*(f(a,c+i*hy)+f(b, c+i*hy)+f(a+j*hx,c)+f(a+j*hx,d))+((hx*hy)*f(a+j*hx,c+i*hy))

    return integral


def t(x,y):
    return x*(y**(2))

print(double_integral(t,0,2,0,1,10,10))
```

Comment: Why did you remove the code?

Comment: I didn't think it made sense

Answer (score 4):

A few problems in your code:

First yes your indentation here is off (but I assume it's from not copying it across well since this would lead to an error rather than a wrong value). In the future make sure the indentation in your question corresponds to what you have at on your own computer before posting...

Then a term should be added within a `for` if and only if it's in the corresponding sum... Here you put everything within the double `for` loop which corresponds to having all the terms in the double sum.

Finally `range(1,n)` already stops at `n-1` only so you want to remove those `-1` in the ranges.

In the end:

```
def double_integral(f,a,b,c,d,nx,ny):

    hx = (b-a)/nx
    hy = (d-c)/ny 

    first_term = (f(a,c)+f(a,d)+f(b,c)+f(b,d))

    i_sum = 0
    for i in range(1,ny):
        i_sum += f(a,c+i*hy)+f(b, c+i*hy)

    j_sum = 0
    for j in range(1,nx):
        j_sum += f(a+j*hx,c)+f(a+j*hx,d)

    ij_sum = 0
    for i in range(1,ny):
        for j in range(1,nx):
            ij_sum += f(a+j*hx,c+i*hy)

    integral = (first_term/4 + i_sum/2 + j_sum/2 + ij_sum) * hx * hy

    return integral


def t(x,y):
    return x*(y**(2))

print(double_integral(t,0,2,0,1,10,10))

0.6700000000000003
```

You'll get closer to `2/3` by choosing  numbers of steps larger than `10`...

And you can be more pythonic by using sum comprehension:

```
def double_integral(f,a,b,c,d,nx,ny):
    hx = (b-a)/nx
    hy = (d-c)/ny 
    first_term = (f(a,c)+f(a,d)+f(b,c)+f(b,d))
    i_sum = sum(f(a,c+i*hy)+f(b, c+i*hy) for i in range (1,ny))
    j_sum = sum(f(a+j*hx,c)+f(a+j*hx,d) for j in range(1,nx))
    ij_sum = sum(f(a+j*hx,c+i*hy) for i in range (1,ny) for j in range(1,nx))
    integral = (first_term/4 + i_sum/2 + j_sum/2 + ij_sum) * hx * hy
    return integral
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful!

Comment: Can I ask what do you mean by your second point: 'Then a term should be added within a for if and only if it's in the corresponding sum... Here you put everything within the double for loop which corresponds to having all the terms in the double sum.' Is it invalid to write for i in range:... and then for j in range....?

Comment: If a term is inside both `for i` and `for j` loops it will be added for all combinations of values of `i` and `j`: `sum(i for i in range(3)) == 0+1+2 == 3` but `sum(i for j in range(10) for i in range(3)) == 30` because you are adding each value of `i` over and over `10` times for each value of `j`.